# How to use ModelBinder classes in Controllers when using Umbraco Cloud

Tags: model-binding, umbraco7, umbraco-cloud

I have an Umbraco Cloud Project I have just started, and for the first time I want to use the ModelBinder.

When using Umbraco Cloud you have a website instead of a Web Application.

You also have a .Core Project where you have a controllers folder. How do I access the generated strongly typed classes in my controllers in my .Core project when the classes are generated in the Website project?

Also, in the past before I started using the model binder, I would always make custom view models, do logic in my controller then pass that custom view model to my view.

When using the Model Binder, assuming I can get the strong types classes in my controller, should I still be making a custom view model class now I have a strong typed object can I just pass that straight in to the view... I'm a little confused about the correct approach, my gut is telling me I should still using a custom view model.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Looks like I have got it working but I'm not 100% sure if this is the way it should be done.

**Step 1.**

Sent Model Binder mode in the web config to DLL with the following settings

```
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable" value="true" />
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="Dll" />
```

This will cause Umbraco to generate model classes based on your Document Types. - (by clicking generate models button) which are located in:

Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.dll in the bin folder. of your .Web project

**Step 2**

From the .Core project Add a reference to Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.dll the bin folder of the .Web project.

Now in your controller classes in your .core project you can now use your strongly typed Generated model like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(HomePage model)
{

        var myvalue = model.SEotitle;  // Look strong typed 

        //more logic here
        return View(model);
}
```

Would love to know if this is how others are using model binder in cloud.